# Spherical Coordinates: Triple Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Using spherical coordinates evaluate:

$ \displaystyle \int_0^3 \
\int_0^{\sqrt{9-y^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{18-x^2-y^2}} (x^2+y^2+z^2) \ dz \ dx \ dy $

From the rough sketch that i drew:

I find out that $\theta$ lies between $0$ and $\pi$/2

Then from the range of the integral of

$z$ = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$\phi$ = $\pi$/4

Thus, $\phi$ lies between $0$ and $\pi$/4

Lastly, for $\rho$

$z$ = ${\sqrt{18-x^2-y^2}}$ , $\rho$ is ${\sqrt{18}}$

Thus, $\rho$ lies between $0$ and ${\sqrt{18}}$

But my answer is wrong, can you please guide me since I think that my range of $\rho$ is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounds you have come up with are correct. You may have made a mistake somewhere in computation.

$I = \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sqrt{18}} \rho^4 \ \sin \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$

$ = \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{972\sqrt2}{5} \sin \phi \ d\phi \ d\theta$

$ = \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{972\sqrt2}{5} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right) \ d\theta$

$ \displaystyle  = \frac{486 \pi}{5} (\sqrt2 - 1)$

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. From your explanations from my previous questions, I have understood this concept much more. Thanks a lot to you! I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Diana indeed good work of identifying bounds. Glad I have been able to help. In the given bounds in cartesian coordinates, I hope it is clear why upper bound of $x$ is $\sqrt{9-y^2}$ and of $y$, it is $3$. That is the circle at the intersection of cone and sphere. $z^2 = x^2 + y^2, x^2+y^2+z^2 = 18 \implies x^2 + y^2 = 9$. So they are integrating over area of that quarter circle with bounds of $z$ between cone and sphere.

Comment: Oh, I have not looked at it that way. Well noted and thanks again